# IOS8 App Icon Submission Failed

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to submit an app with a icon. However, it pops out two errors and simply rejects my submission:

[image]

And,

[image]

This is extremely weird even if I tried so many times with different app icon generators. 
You can download my app icon set here: [appiconset](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3leiBkyvsLDfnl6UEtvNVh4LXB6X2NxaFhkY29LZVc0ZWQ2ZzlIbVJDa1o5cmhKYVl5QlE&usp=sharing)

What's more I use an empty pages for launch images, one is 640*960 one is 640*1136.

Is there anyone could help me out? I think apple docs for this issue is really brief and bring too much trouble for everyone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I remove my old archive then archive again.
It is fixed. Xcode seems not update.

Answer (score 2):

Select the images.xcassets from the project navigation on left side.[image]

There if you have checked iOS7 and later sizes, then you will have to set all the required assets, the xCode presents you with.

[image]

You may have missed specifying the 4th or 5th icon image properly. By properly, I meant specify 120x120 pixels image which has to be in .png format.

[image]

About the 2nd error. I think, you haven't specified the launch image.

Under general Tab, go to "App icon and Launch Images" section and click on the right arrow beside the Launch images. [image]

This will take you to -

[image]

Again, set the images properly.

Comment: thanks, but I did this already. I am not sure why the error is still there. Is there any other possibilities?

Comment: Have you checked if you have right pixels for your images?

Comment: yeah I did, please take a look: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3leiBkyvsLDfnl6UEtvNVh4LXB6X2NxaFhkY29LZVc0ZWQ2ZzlIbVJDa1o5cmhKYVl5QlE&authuser=0

Comment: this is the current app icon set and launch images, I think they are all good, but apple keeps rejecting

Comment: I also remove the alpha channel

Comment: what's more, I pass the validation on my machine but when I submit it to App Store, it failed.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't have icon size 120x120. plz make 120x120 size icon

Comment: I have got Icon-60@2x.png, is this 120x120 icon?

Comment: i know that if icon-60@2x.png add AppIcon, Application do it.
but actually if you have some time, you should better make icon40@3x.png and icon60@2x.png.
that is same size but different work